# LawOfCosines solving for c, but getting odd answer

Tags: c++, trigonometry

I have been trying to code a program that can solve for c using the Law Of Cosines. The program runs correctly, but the answer I get is ridiculously big, noted by how it was in scientific notation.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
class TrigMath
{
    private: 
    double a;
    double b;
    double y;

    public:
    double LawOfCos()
    {
        return sqrt(pow(a,2) + pow(b,2) - 2*a*b*cos(y));
    }

    void seta(double A)
    {
        A = a;
    }

    void setb(double B)
    {
        B = b;
    }

    void sety(double Y)
    {
        Y = y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    TrigMath triangle1;
    triangle1.seta(3);
    triangle1.setb(4);
    triangle1.sety(60);

    cout << "c is equal to " << triangle1.LawOfCos() << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cos` takes radians, not degrees

Comment: The ridiculous large number may come from the uninitialized variables: `a`, `b` and `y` are never initialized, the assignments swapped.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how they are uninitialized? I assumed they were, based on the private section of my class. Unless you mean setting them to some value within the class, which I can try. Tried that, it gave me 1, although the answer I was supposed to get was root 13.

Comment: @NSandhar C++ doesn't initialize for you. You need to do that in the constructor. Your setters are going backwards,  too, but you don't need those anyway.

Comment: FYI, multiplying (a * a) is more efficient than `pow(a,2)`.  You are eliminating the overhead of function calling and return.  Some compilers may recognize this pattern on higher optimization levels.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Surprisingly GCC will optimize `pow(x, 2)` as `x*x` with `-O3`: https://godbolt.org/z/y8wVJb but in general I'd never rely on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cos() function there takes input as radians not as degrees.

Try to convert degrees to radians and then supply it as input.

In the class functions seta, setb and sety you have written A = a, B = b and Y = y.
You have to change them to a = A, b = B and Y = y.

So after applying all the changs the code should be like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
class TrigMath
{
    private: 
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    double y = 0;

    public:
    double LawOfCos()
    {
        return sqrt(pow(a,2) + pow(b,2) - 2*a*b*cos(y));
    }

    void seta(double A)
    {
        a = A;
    }

    void setb(double B)
    {
        b = B;
    }

    void sety(double Y)
    {
        y = Y*3.14/180;
    }
};

int main()
{
    TrigMath triangle1;
    triangle1.seta(3.0);
    triangle1.setb(4.0);
    triangle1.sety(60.0);

    cout << "c is equal to " << triangle1.LawOfCos() << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would setting the y value to the radian equivalent also work? This didn't work, but I tried what you suggested. The value I got was even higher.

Comment: Yes, it will work. But also initialise the private variables to some value as they might be the reason for ridiculous large numbers as pointed out by svenihoney.

Comment: Based on your latest edit, the program now works as intended. Thanks!